# SessionRunHook returning empty SessionRunValues after run

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to write a hook that will allow me to compute some global metrics (rather than batch-wise metrics). To prototype, I thought I'd get a simple hook up and running that would capture and remember true positives. It looks like this:

```
class TPHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord):
        print("Starting Hook")

        tp_name = 'metrics/f1_macro/TP'
        self.tp = []
        self.args = session.graph.get_operation_by_name(tp_name)
        print(f"Got Args: {self.args}")

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        print("Starting Before Run")
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(self.args)

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        print("After Run")
        print(f"Got Values: {run_values.results}")
```

However, the values returned in the "after_run" part of the hook are always None. I tested this in both the train and evaluation phase. Am I misunderstanding something about how the SessionRunHooks are supposed to work?

---

Maybe relevant information:
The model was build in keras and converted to an estimator with the `keras.estimator.model_to_estimator()` function. The model has been tested and works fine, and the op that I'm trying to retrieve in the hook is defined in this code block:

```
def _f1_macro_vector(y_true, y_pred):
    """Computes the F1-score with Macro averaging.

    Arguments:
        y_true {tf.Tensor} -- Ground-truth labels
        y_pred {tf.Tensor} -- Predicted labels

    Returns:
        tf.Tensor -- The computed F1-Score
    """
    y_true = K.cast(y_true, tf.float64)
    y_pred = K.cast(y_pred, tf.float64)

    TP = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * K.round(y_pred), axis=0, name='TP')
    FN = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * (1 - K.round(y_pred)), axis=0, name='FN')
    FP = tf.reduce_sum((1 - y_true) * K.round(y_pred), axis=0, name='FP')

    prec = TP / (TP + FP)
    rec = TP / (TP + FN)

    # Convert NaNs to Zero
    prec = tf.where(tf.is_nan(prec), tf.zeros_like(prec), prec)
    rec = tf.where(tf.is_nan(rec), tf.zeros_like(rec), rec)

    f1 = 2 * (prec * rec) / (prec + rec)

    # Convert NaN to Zero
    f1 = tf.where(tf.is_nan(f1), tf.zeros_like(f1), f1)

    return f1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into the same problem, I found out how to restructure the program so that it worked. Although the documentation makes it sound like I can pass raw ops into the `SessionRunArgs`, it seems like it requires actual tensors (maybe this is a misreading on my part).
This is pretty easy to accomplish - I just changed the `after_create_session` code to what's shown below.

```
def after_create_session(self, session, coord):

    tp_name = 'metrics/f1_macro/TP'
    self.tp = []
    tp_tensor = session.graph.get_tensor_by_name(tp_name+':0')

    self.args = [tp_tensor]
```

And this successfully runs.